# Android - FileProvider getUriForFile when the file is on an external SD

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-fileprovider

Currently, FileProvider getUriForFile method generates IllegalArgumentException when the file is on an external SD

When the file is in the device memory (under /storage/emulated/0), it works fine.

```
 Uri videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
            new File(videoPath));
```

here videoPath had the following value :

```
videoPath =  /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.podcastcutter.debug/files/episodeMp3/TEDTalks (video)/Why you should love statistics - Alan Smith.mp4
```

My Manifest file contains :

```
       <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

and here the provider_paths :

```
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

How can I modify the FileProvider configuration to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Exception generated:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.podcastcutter.debug/files/episodeMp3/TEDTalks (video)/Why you should love statistics - Alan Smith.mp4 
android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)                  
android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
```

**Additional Configuration information:**

```
compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

minSdkVersion 16

targetSdkVersion 25

support libraries version : 25.1.1
```

Comment: You better extend the ContentProvider class. Then you can serve files from every storage location. Much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I modify the FileProvider configuration to solve this problem?

You can't. `FileProvider` does not support removable storage.

Comment: Got it. I eventually implemented my own video activity.

Answer (score 37):

I added in my provider.xml this line and works fine to get file URI from SD card:

`<root-path name="external_files" path="/storage/" />`

Complete xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: This has to be the accepted answer, even it is not in the official documentation.

Comment: @Rodrigo Jardim.thank you so much this worked perfectly . i wasted  whole to tofix this by following other answers

Comment: You got to be kidding me. Thx - your answer works for me, as well.

Comment: Paths should have different names, otherwise FileProvider will be initialized with only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your provider path is the wrong type. Your `videoPath` shows a path to your app's external storage but your provider path is using `external-path` which links to the device root external storage. (`/storage/emulated/0`)

Change your provider path to be `<external-files-path>...</external-files-path>`

Comment: Could you be more explicit please. What path should I add?